# Navegacion en JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

estoy empezando a trabajar con JSF y en el proyecto estoy usando primefaces y tengo una vista que es la principal que cargo en mi proyecto, que es una lista de tareas el alcance que he utilizado para el bean es @SessionScoped porque, nesesito despues de cargar la lista de tareas tomar dos valores de la tarea seleccionada, para poder  cargar en la siguiente vista, todos los datos de la tarea y poder asignar un colaborador y otros datos a esa tarea, esta vista en donde se asigna colaborador tiene alcance @ViewScoped la asignacion de la tarea la realiza bien, pero el problema es en la vista que carga la tarea tengo un boton regresar a lista de tareas el codigo que utilizo es este:

```
<p:commandButton value="Regresar a lista de tareas" onclick="window.history.back();" >  
</p:commandButton>
```

el problema es que al regresar a la lista de tareas deberia recargar la lista para eliminar la tarea que ya a sido asignada, pero no recarga la lista la tarea sigue apareciendo y tambien al darle en el boton para asignar otra tarea no carga la siguiente vista se queda cargando

el codigo del bean de lista de tareas es este:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ManagedBean(name="tareacontrolador")
@SessionScoped
public class TareaControlador implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<Tarea> listaTarea;
private TareaDaoImpl dao = new TareaDaoImpl();
private String numExpe;
private String numRefe;
private Tarea tareaSeleccionada;
private Usuario usu;
private String direccionamiento;

@ManagedProperty("#{login}")
private Login login;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.direccionamiento = "";
    this.tareaSeleccionada = null;
    listar();

}


public List<Tarea>  listar() {

    this.tareaSeleccionada = new Tarea();
    this.listaTarea = new ArrayList<Tarea>();
    usu = new Usuario();

    usu = login.getU();
    String usuario = usu.getUsuario();
    String tipoUsuario = usu.getTipoUsuario();
    String actividadActual="";

    if(tipoUsuario.equals("CC") || tipoUsuario.equals("A")) {

        actividadActual = "ASIGNACION";

        this.direccionamiento = "entrega";

    }
    else if(tipoUsuario.equals("CG")) {

        actividadActual = "REALIZACION";

        this.direccionamiento= "recibe";

    }

    try {
        listaTarea = dao.listaTareas(usuario, actividadActual, tipoUsuario);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listaTarea;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese problema te sucede porque tu Bean es del tipo `@SessionScoped` al realizar la redireccion el método `@PostConstruct` ya no se ejecutara porque el Bean de sesión solo se crea una vez y según el código depende del método `listar()` para recargar las tareas.

Además la forma en que redireccionas no es una forma recomendada, si quieres una forma sencilla puedes agregar la librería omnifaces 3 que te ofrece varias herramientas como descargas de archivo, redirección, envió de parámetros entre vistas, etc. Una solucion simple seria crear un nuevo método que llames desde tu botón  "Regresar a lista de tareas" ejecutar listar y realizar la redirección.

```
public void regresar(){  
    //Primero llamamos el metodo para recargar la lista.
    listar();

    // A continuación elije uno de estos 2 métodos nativo con jsf o con librería omnifaces 3
    //Opcion 1 utilizando JSF (import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;) si la url es http://localhost:8080/usuario/tareas.xhtml
    try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/usuario/tareas.xhtml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Opcion 2 Utilizando Omnifaces (import org.omnifaces.util.Faces;) si la url es http://localhost:8080/usuario/tareas.xhtml
    Faces.redirect("/usuario/tareas.xhtml");
}

 <p:commandButton value="Regresar a lista de tareas" actionListener="#{tareacontrolador.regresar()}" />
```